# OpenMP: parallel for(i;...) and i value

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I have a following parallel snippet:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{

omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int i;
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
    {
#pragma omp for 
        for(i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
            printf("A  %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),i);
        }
#pragma omp critical
        printf("i  %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i ); 
    }
}
```

I thought that after the loop, each thread will have `i` equal to `i` last value in the thread's loop. My *desired* output would be:

```
A  0: 0
A  0: 1
A  0: 2
A  3: 9
A  2: 6
A  2: 7
A  2: 8
A  1: 3
A  1: 4
A  1: 5
i  0: 3
i  3: 10
i  2: 9
i  1: 6
```

whereas what I get is:

```
A  0: 0
A  0: 1
A  0: 2
A  3: 9
A  2: 6
A  2: 7
A  2: 8
A  1: 3
A  1: 4
A  1: 5
i  0: -1217085452
i  3: -1217085452
i  2: -1217085452
i  1: -1217085452
```

How to make `i` to hold last iteration's value? `lastprivate(i)` makes `i = 10` for all threads, and that is not what I want.

Comment: can you explain what you wanted to do with the information?

Comment: The `private` directive in OpenMP is completely useless in C++ and modern C. Just declare your private variables inside the parallel block – there’s no reason ever not to do this.

Comment: @sehe: I was writing why I need this information for, and I just realized that actually maybe I don't need it :) But, I have learned something about `parallel for`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out you can't. OpenMP alters program semantics.

Parallel for loops are rewritten by the compiler according to well-defined set of rules.

This also implies you cannot break from, return from such a loop. You can also not directly manipulate the loop variable. The loop condition can not call random functions or do any conditional expression, in short: **a `omp parallel for` loop is *not* a for loop**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{

omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i;
#pragma omp for 
        for(i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
            printf("A  %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),i);
        }
#pragma omp critical
        printf("i  %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sehe`s post, I figure out the following dirty trick that solves the problem

```
    int i, last_i;
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
    {
#pragma omp for 
        for(i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
            printf("A  %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),i);
            last_i = i;
        }
#pragma omp critical
        printf("i  %d: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), last_i ); 
    }
}
```